# How to encapsulate height and width of an image with java.awt.Dimension object and pass it to a method like 235 x 265

Tags: java, awt

Java: How can I encapsulate height and width with java.awt.Dimension object (in java) to look like 235 x 265 and and then pass it to a method. Would that be then passed as an integer array? If so, how? Your contributions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Start by looking at the [docs for java.awt.Dimension](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html).

Comment: No, it would be passed as a Dimension object. Object can be passed around, just like real objects.

Comment: @JB Nizet You really seem to understand my problem here. Please could you just give a very simple example on how to pass the dimension parameter to a method as an argument.

Comment: ...Or can anyone else help me with a concrete example of how to pass a dimension object to a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are meant to be used as types for variables, and can of course be passed as arguments to methods. So here's an example:

```
public class DimensionPrinter
    public void printDimension(Dimension d) {
        System.out.println("Here's the dimension width : " + d.getWidth());
        System.out.println("Here's the dimension height : " + d.getHeight());
    }
}
```

And here's an example using the above method:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dimension dimension = new Dimension(800, 600);
        DimensionPrinter printer = new DimensionPrinter();
        printer.printDimension(dimension);
    }
}
```

(imports omitted)

This is extremely basic stuff that you need to understand before doing any serious development, especially GUI development, which is hard.

If you learnt something thanks to this answer, then it's a sign that you should read an introductory book about Java and OO. The [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html) is also a good read.